"The method "isEnabled" in class "App\Entity\Brand" requires 0 arguments, but should accept only 1"
I'm trying to save a simple form in database using doctrine. The entity I've created - lets name it Brand - using php bin/console make:entity has a boolean property:
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BrandRepository::class)]
class Brand
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $is_enabled = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function isEnabled(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->is_enabled;
    }

    public function setEnabled(bool $is_enabled): static
    {
        $this->is_enabled = $is_enabled;

        return $this;
    }
}

This entity is completely auto-generated and I changed nothing. I also have created a form-type using php bin/console make:crud command. The generated form-type named BrandType is shown below:
class BrandType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('is_enabled', CheckboxType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                // I tried these 2 options, but didn't help:
                // 'empty_data' => false,
                // 'false_values' => [false],
                'value' => true
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Brand::class,
        ]);
    }
}

As you can see below, the form handler is so simple:
#[Route('/brand')]
class BrandController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $brand = new Brand();
        $form = $this->createForm(BrandType::class, $brand);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager->persist($brand);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('blah', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->render('brand/new.html.twig', [
            'brand' => $brand,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
}

But when I submit the form, I get this error:

The method "isEnabled" in class "App\Entity\Catalog\Brand" requires 0
arguments, but should accept only 1..

And the exception highlights the $form->handleRequest($request); line in controller. I'm using PHP 8.3.6 with Symfony 6.4.10 and the doctrine packages I'm using are listed below:
"doctrine/dbal": "^3",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.12",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
"doctrine/orm": "^3.2",


Logically the property should just be named enabled, with the setter setEnabled and the getter isEnabled. You could try renaming the property or the getter to getIsEnabled. See also https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/54885

@chris_cm you were exactly right. I removed the is_enabled property and added a enabled property and all work fine now. Please post your comment as an answer so i can accept it. And it also may help other peoples. Thank you.

Logically the property of the class Brand should be named enabled, with a setter setEnabled and a getter isEnabled.
To solve the error, rename the property to enabled or alternatively rename the getter to getIsEnabled.
See also this discussion.
